# How do I create a new table through combining similar elements from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm a complete newbie to SQL and trying to learn it on my own for a project in a class, so I'm a bit lost/overwhelmed with trying to figure out how to do this...I just started yesterday.

Essentially, I'm trying to model a super basic warehousing call, where you have an individual table of demand from different vendors from a pool of items you store. You also have a table with information relating to those items. Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Properties (
SKU INT PRIMARY KEY,
Xdim FLOAT,
Ydim FLOAT,
Zdim FLOAT,
Weight FLOAT,
QTYavail INT
);

INSERT INTO Properties (
SKU, Xdim, Ydim, Zdim, Weight, QTYavail)
VALUES
(1001, 3, 4, 5, 2.5, 50),
(1002, 2, 4, 6, 1.15, 60); 

CREATE TABLE Order_1 (
SKU INT,
QTY INT);

CREATE TABLE Order_2 (
SKU INT,
QTY INT);

CREATE TABLE Order_3 (
SKU INT,
QTY INT);

INSERT INTO Order_1 (
SKU, QTY)
VALUES
(1001, 10),
(1002, 4);

INSERT INTO Order_2 (
SKU, QTY)
VALUES
(1001, 3),
(1002, 1);

INSERT INTO Order_3 (
SKU, QTY)
VALUES
(1001, 6);
```

My goal is to combine all this into one comprehensive table where I combine the total demand per SKU...for example here, SKU 1001 would QTYdemand of 19. My columns on the table would be

SKU
Xdim
Ydim
Zdim
Weight
QTYdemand
QTYavail

I've managed to learn how to combine the orders and the relative SKU demand via this code:

```
SELECT SKU, SUM(QTY) QTYdemand
from
(
SELECT * FROM Order_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Order_2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Order_3
) x
group by SKU;
```

But I have no idea how to further use this query, and have no idea if this is the right path to begin with.

Any help or suggestions are all greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're doing it wrong. all orders go into a single table, all skus/items go into their own table.

Comment: I could certainly design it that way pretty easily, but I wanted to set it up where I was receiving orders on an individual basis and then consolidate from there. Would it make more sense/be more reasonable to simply have new orders added to a grand table of demand as you're suggesting?

Comment: yes. a million yes. what happens when you get a 4th order, or a 5th? you continually have to change your query to incorporate more tables. instead, you just have an auto incrementing order_id in your super-order table, which also has info about the order such as who ordered it, date it was ordered etc, then all products for the order go in their own table again, lets say `order_products`, with the order_id from the orders table, the sku from the products table, and the quantity.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying. Makes a lot of sense, thanks for your input!

Comment: fyi, that process is called 'normalisation', and everyone doing db work needs to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orders should be individualized by their unique ID (primary key), not by them being stored in a separate table.

In most scenarios, you would maintain a table for orders and a table for products.  Then you would have a many-to-many relationship between orders and products, in a database, this would be represented by a third table with a composite key (primary key consisting of id from Order and an id from Product).

Therefore, you end up with three tables (primary keys in italics):

**Order:** *id*, date, any other data relevant to the entire order

**Product:** *id*, name, any other data relevant to the product

**OrderProduct:** *order_id, product_id*, qty

The Order table consisting of a record for each order, the Product table consisting of a record for each product, and a OrderProduct table consisting of a record for each product that is in an order.  OrderProduct can have multiple rows for each order and multiple rows for each product, but a unique combination for a specific order and specific product.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed rundown. Makes a lot more sense to implement it this way! Guess I got stuck on the how versus the why =P.